# Reshaping torch tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a torch of shape `(1,3,8)`. I want to increase the first dimension to `n`, resulting in the final tensor of shape `(n,3,8)`. I want to pad zeroes of that shape. Here is what I worked on:

```
n = 5
a = torch.randn(1,3,8) # Random (1,3,8) tensor
b = torch.cat((a,torch.zeros_like(a)))
for i in range(n-2):
    b = torch.cat((b,torch.zeros_like(a)))
print(b.shape) # (5,3,8)
```

This works, but is there a better and more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the loop by creating a tensor of zeros of length `n-1` straight away:

```
torch.cat((a, torch.zeros(n - 1, a.shape[1], a.shape[2])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.pad.html) function, e.g.,

```py
n = 5
a = torch.randn(1,3,8)

b = torch.nn.functional.pad(a, (0, 0, 0, 0, n - 1, 0), value=0)

print(b.shape)
torch.Size([5, 3, 8])
```

Note that the values in the tuple `(0, 0, 0, 0, n - 1, 0)` work through the dimensions from last to first, i.e., the initial two zeros mean pad  0 points to the last dimension, while the last two values (`n - 1` and `0`) mean pad `n - 1` values to the back of the first dimension and 0 values to the front.